# XSS Validation on body .NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, security, xss

I am trying to resolve an issue on my application,
whenever I receive a request on an mvc application I am using a filter (an registering it on global.asax):

```
public class XSSAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.HttpContext.Request.InputStream.Position = 0;
        string body = null;
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.InputStream))
        {
            body = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
        bool isBodyValid = ***********
        if (!isBodyValid)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to know how to validate the body for XSS vulnerability.
Thanks.

Comment: take a look at this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.antixss(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Or this: https://github.com/mganss/HtmlSanitizer

Comment: Why do you need it anyway? MVC has a built-in mechanism for anti-XSS request validation (`ValidateInput` attribute), and it is enabled by default. You can see how it works [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/HttpRequest.cs,ad040181e60c14c7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validating requests is not the best way to prevent XSS. [Even microsoft get this wrong](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/80089/8340). [See here](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/100185/8340) for some more examples.

The best way is to correctly encode upon output. For example, in HTML change `<` to `&lt;`. Different encoding is needed though for output to Javascript contexts. Check out the [OWASP XSS (Cross Site Scripting) Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to know how to validate the body for XSS vulnerability.

**When it comes to security, first, leverage the tools available rather than writing your own when possible.**

As some have pointed out, ASP.Net MVC already has some baked-in capabilities when it comes to validating a request against XSS.  For preventing XSS deep-dive on the ASP.Net framework (as well as for client and other application specific areas) you can check out [**this**](http://lockmedown.com/preventing-xss-in-asp-net-made-easy/) (see **Server** section).

However, the quick and dirty is:

ASP.Net provides [Request Validation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh882339(v=vs.110).aspx) out-of-the-box that can perform the required validation.  You can also leverage the more granular control (attribute) [ValidateInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.validateinputattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) for turning on or off specific action methods.

Finally, What version of ASP.Net are you using? Up to ASP.Net v4, they started incorporating (some) of the [AntiXSS](https://wpl.codeplex.com/) library features in `System.Web.Security.AntiXss` but were still using some blacklist approaches and using the AntiXSS libraries is encouraged.

However, According to the latest of ASP.Net v5, they are supposedly using an all whitelist approach.  But I believe the AntiXSS library will still provides some additional features (not necessarily for validating the Request).

It must be mentioned that AntiXSS library has reached end-of-life.

Answer (score 0):

The ASP.NET MVC framework is already secured against XSS attacks : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh882339(v=vs.110).aspx.

If a user try to send html content, the framework will throw an exception before launching the controller method (or even the `Application_BeginRequest` method of the global.asax).

Answer (score 0):

You can use from Microsoft [AntiXss](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AntiXSS/4.3.0) Library

Comment: it's now part of dot net.